# Concat two WinJS.Binding.List into one

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

I am trying to combine 2 `WinJS.Binding.List` into one. I saw the `.concat` method on MSDN, but it doesn't seem to work. Can somebody show me how to do it?

Input:

```
var a = new WinJS.Binding.List([1,2])
var b = new WinJS.Binding.List([3,4])
```

Expected output: a WinJS.Binding.List that has number 1,2,3,4 in it.

I tried `a.concat(b)`, but it returns a 3-element array instead of a `WinJS.Binding.List`. Here is the logs in console.

```
var a = new WinJS.Binding.List([1,2])
var b = new WinJS.Binding.List([3,4])
a.concat(b)
==> [object Array][...]
```

Any ideas why and how to do it correctly?

P.S. I know I can loop through every item in `b` and push into `a`, but is there a more efficient way of doing it? I also don't want to concat the array before converting them into `WinJS.Binding.List` because I am making 2 async calls from 2 different data source. The code above is just a simplified example.

Comment: Have you thought about having one big list from the start and then presenting this to the application layer as two separate lists via a filtered and/or sorted projection?

Comment: Along with @ma_il suggestion, you can use `WinJS.Promise.join` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211774.aspx) to await multiple async calls. Then you can combine both of the results into one array and make your `WinJS.Binding.List` from that. Would that not work?

Comment: @ma_il and @GotDibbs Thanks for the suggestions. My plan was to bind an empty source to the ListView first, then modify the datasource to reflect the changes. I don't want to use `join` because I want the data show up asap instead of resolving at the same time and then add to the ListView. That's why being able to concat 2 `WinJS.Binding.List` would be a better solution for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could grab the 2 arrays from the list (using slice), concat them and then create a new list.

```
var a = new WinJS.Binding.List([1, 2]);
var b = new WinJS.Binding.List([3, 4]);
var ab = new WinJS.Binding.List(a.slice(0).concat(b.slice(0)));
```

Can also use the list concat method (as opposed to the native js concat) to make it a little shorter:

```
var a = new WinJS.Binding.List([1, 2]);
var b = new WinJS.Binding.List([3, 4]);
var ab = new WinJS.Binding.List(a.concat(b.slice(0)));
```

Answer (score 1):

From your description, I'll assume that your data is returned from different sources and is either (a) already in separate WinJS.Binding.List instances, making a projection unfeasible or (b) semantically different enough to warrant storage in separate List instances.

In that case, my approach would probably be to synchronize the joined list using event listeners along the lines of:

```
[list1, list2].forEach (list) ->
  list.oniteminserted = (event) -> joinedList.push(event.detail.value)
  list.onitemremoved = (event) -> joinedList.splice(joinedList.indexOf(event.detail.value),1)
```

(To be replaced with `addEventListener` and corresponding `removeEventListener` for added complexity ;)) The drawback in this method is that you have little control over the order of the items in the final list, which would warrant another sort predicate, i.e. further overhead in this model.

In the end it may very well be that a good old `.forEach (item) -> joinedList.push(item)` on both lists is the most straightforward and appropriate way to solve this.

Edit: to go a bit more into my suggestion of using a projection, I had in mind something like this:

```
# put all items in the "big" list
item1.source = 'list1'
joinedList.push(item1)
item2.source = 'list2'
joinedList.push(item2)
# create separate lists using projection
list1 = joinedList.createFiltered (i) -> i.source is 'list1'
list2 = joinedList.createFiltered (i) -> i.source is 'list2'
```